# How to check the current model before retrieving a record with a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

Given the following polymorphic relationship:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :noteable, polymorphic: true

  has_one :garden, foreign_key: :id, primary_key: :noteable_id
end

class Garden < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes, as: :noteable
end
```

I'd like to verify that `noteable_type` is `Garden` to prevent mismatches.

What is a good implementation for this problem?

Comment: I think polymorphic association does it by default.

Comment: Can you explain why this is useful? A `Note` does not really have one garden, it may or may not belong to a `Garden` but it certainly has no ownership of one, so I am trying to understand the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build_in `is_a?` method to check what the associated record is. So basically you can check it is a garden by doing:

`Note.find(1).garden.is_a? Garden`

If this is true, you are sure it is indeed a garden.

Just a tip: I'd change the name of the has_one, because this already assumes it is a garden, while it can be something else in a polymorphic relationship.